# URL displays the source code

Tags: jsf

in my application particular URL displays the JavaScript source used in our project.For                         >`https://example/faces/scripts/NameofJavaScript.js`. It displays the java script mentioned in the URL as save or open option.please let me know about this issue.Is it Web server side issue or Application side issue.how to resolve this issue.I am using Java with Jsf. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always minimize your javascript (with like http://jscompress.com/). People will still be able to see it, but it will be harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop people from viewing your JavaScript code sadly; as it's a client side language, however if you were to use PHP or ASP.Net for example, the code would be hidden as it's server side.

Client Side - View able
Server Side - Hidden

Basic rules I go by anyway